# Adding logging to glibc APIs

Tags: c, linux, glibc

I want to add logs to certain APIs inside glibc , Does glibc already has a logging mechanism which I can use?
I want to log to a file.

Comment: what is this? I couldn't understand

Comment: like there is an API localtime(), I want to add logs inside this , so that I write to a file from inside the API.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I will modify glibc for this.

Comment: This is probably not what you want to do. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: ok, I want to see which all processes/threads are calling localtime and a few other APIs I want to monitor for some reason.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer  I generally do such unusual stuff :P so quite normal for me :D

Comment: @stng Then you'll probably have to do it yourself and compile glbic yourself. But be ware, that all of this is hard. Obviously, you can't just use functions defined in glibc in itself willy-hilly. E.g., to debug `printf`, you can't use printf.

Comment: Could you use SystemTap?

Comment: @stng your reply to me is a non-answer. This is a Q&A site. Your question is "is there a logging mechanism in glibc", well, the answer is NO. But very often, people don't ask the right question and I thought we can actually help you, if you'd tell us your intent. But you don't, so we can't.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file localtime.c:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static  struct tm * (*real_localtime)(const time_t *clock) = NULL;

/* wrapping localtime function call */
struct tm * localtime(const time_t *clock)
{
    printf("Who called me? %d\n", getuid());

    /* Fetch the real localtime function from glibc */
    real_localtime = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "localtime");
    return real_localtime(clock);
}
```

Compile it this way:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -o localtime.so localtime.c -ldl
```

Run commands this way:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/your/localtime.so /path/to/app/using/localtime
```

I created this test app:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main () {
   time_t rawtime;
   struct tm *info;
   time( &rawtime );
   info = localtime( &rawtime );
   printf("Current local time and date: %s", asctime(info));
   return(0);
}
```

And tested the lib:

```
% cc -c localtime.c && gcc -fPIC -shared -o localtime.so localtime.c -ldl ; cc -o x x.c ; sh -c "LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/your/localtime.so ./x"
Who called me? 1001
Current local time and date: Fri Sep  2 13:25:00 2022
```

I just used `printf()`, but you can choose to log via `syslog()` or open and write to a log file of your choice. This allows you to intercept any call and perform actions before the real call is called.

Comment: The problem is, that OP did not tell us what they INTEND TO DO. If they want to log stuff for a single function, ok, fine, but glbic has thousands of functions. So this doesn't scale. And if you simply want to know which function was called, you could save yourself the trouble and use something like `ltrace`.

Comment: `ltrace` allows you to specify a filter, e.g., to include or exclude certain symbols: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html

Comment: so, ltrace not available on the system.

Comment: and i dont have any benefit from doing printf , I need to log it to file or something else.

Comment: SO my question was if the developers of glibc already have built a mechanism to log or not?